# jQuery Fancybox Not Recognizing Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

```
<a id="attachment3655" rel="Lightbox_109160" href="https://xenogamers.org/attachment.php?attachmentid=3655&d=1350682390">
<img class="thumbnail" border="0" style="float:CONFIG" alt="Click image for larger version.  Name: 253635_10150631007825720_595485719_18819556_7955719_n.jpg  Views: 32  Size: 100.9 KB  ID: 3655" src="https://xenogamers.org/attachment.php?attachmentid=3655&d=1359000187&thumb=1" title="Click image for larger version.  Name: 253635_10150631007825720_595485719_18819556_7955719_n.jpg  Views: 32  Size: 100.9 KB  ID: 3655">
</a>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#attachment3655").fancybox({
        openEffect: 'none',
        closeEffect: 'none'
    });
});
```

It won't recognize the a id at all, and I can't figure out why. I can't change the source above easily so I cannot figure out a way to do this with only jquery.

I've been working on it here: http://jsfiddle.net/2k8EP/226/

Comment: in the fiddle, you are correctly selecting the element. http://jsfiddle.net/2k8EP/227/

Comment: Yes but it isn't enabling the fancybox. If I select .thumbnail it works, but won't for the id of the a tag.

Comment: Right, but the problem has nothing to do with the id, the problem is fancybox works on the image but not the anchor tag.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhh so should I just try and find whatever is in the a tag, so something like $("#attachment3655").find(".thumbnail").fancybox({
?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `type: "image"` to your API options

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#attachment3655").fancybox({
        openEffect: 'none',
        closeEffect: 'none',
        type: "image"
    });
});
```

Your **[forked jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zkHUj/)**

BTW, that is documented [HERE](http://www.fancyapps.com/fancybox/#support), tab FAQ, number 5.

Comment: Yeah it's making me wait 4 more minutes :|