# Fancy-box gallery just linking to image in HTML window

Tags: java, jquery, servlets, fancybox, image-gallery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery Fancybox Not Recognizing Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14511090/jquery-fancybox-not-recognizing-element)

I have a fancy box image gallery which is generated dynamically by image inside of a database. I use a servlet that gets the images from a database, and link to them in the src as per the examples on the fancy-box website. However i cant seem to get it to work When i click on the thumbnail of an image it just links to a seperate page with the image in it rather than the popup image gallery.

When i put in the link to my servlet like below:

```
<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery<%= h.getHomeID()%>" href="http://localhost:8080/Website/Image?id=<%= h.getHomeID()%>" title="Photo">
    <img src="Image?id=<%= h.getHomeID()%>" alt="" height="197px" width="315px"/>
</a>
```

This causes the image to be displayed in a browser window

Using the already provided links from the fancy box page the image gallery seems to work.

```
<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery<%= h.getHomeID()%>" href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8490/8215600456_de252d155d_b.jpg" title="Photo">
    <img src="Image?id=<%= h.getHomeID()%>" alt="" height="197px" width="315px"/>
</a>
```

Would anyone know why this would possibly happen? if needed i can post my servlet code if that would be considered a problem here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14511204/1055987

Comment: http://www.fancyapps.com/fancybox/#support  tab FAQ, number 5.